# How to get the text value of an element in Groovy from within a soap envelope XML message

Tags: java, regex, grails, xpath, groovy

I have string like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <NS1:createResponse xmlns:NS1="http://abc.ru/esf/dto/srvMessages">
         <NS1:Header>
            <integrationID>wd457665grtyy5444</integrationID>
            <nativeID/>
            <resultInfo>
               <status>ERROR</status>
               <errorInfo>
                  <descr>Error:ESB-002: Failed to createSub. Code=Error whilst processing message:Fault from GW: faultcode=tns:Client faultstring=Could not map property BonusMalusRateForKSK detail=,,</descr>
               </errorInfo>
            </resultInfo>
         </NS1:Header>
      </NS1:createResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I have code like:

```
MessageExchange[] me = myTestStepResult.getMessageExchanges()
            log.info "[ERROR] " + me[0].getResponseContent() 
            def matches = me[0].getResponseContent()  =~ '<errorInfo>(.+?)</errorInfo>'
            log.info "[Result" + matches
```

What I'm trying to do with groovy is to get message between `<errorInfo</errorInfo>` tag 
But as result I have like: `java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=<errorInfo>(.+?)</errorInfo> region=0,790 lastmatch=]`

Can you help me to get response text with groovy

Comment: `<errorInfo>\s*<descr>([^<]+)</descr>`.

Comment: You can try: \<descr(.+)

Comment: Still have this error: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern= \<descr(.+) region=0,18 lastmatch=]

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this as XPath. In Groovy [you should use `GPath`](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath), which is very similar. [Never, never ever, use regular expressions with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/111575), it'll always bite you back. If not now, then later. The nested tags, encodings, self-closing, white-space handling, DTD validation, entity parsing, CDATA sections, relevance or not of comments, and not in the least, namespaces, make it *very hard* to get a stable regex that will always succeed.

You can get the node you are interested in with GPath as follows:

```
def bookId = response.'**'.find { book->
    book.author.text() == 'Lewis Carroll'
}.@id
```

Where `**` stands for "depth first". Translated to your example it'll be something like this:

```
def matches = me[0].getResponseContent().'**'.find { node->
    node.name() == 'errorInfo'
}.descr.text()
```

Alternatively, [here's a way to use "true" XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268006/how-do-i-create-an-xpath-function-in-groovy) within Groovy.

Comment: It give me: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script15.groovy: 123: expecting '}', found '->' @ line 123, column 67. ntent().'**'.find { node->node->name() = ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting '}', found '->' @ line 123, column 67. at

Comment: @java_user, sorry, it should've been `.`, not `->`, as your error says. Fixed, see update.

Comment: Says: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ** for class: java.lang.String

Comment: @java_user, These methods are auto-imported. No, like `node-> node.name()...`. Have you [read that link](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath)? I think your object may not yet be groovified, check groovy's [XmlParser](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) for the appropriate method you need for your document. Is it java's `XmlDocument`, or SAX?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply go on with the xmlHolder. Which is pretty simple

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("RequestStepName#Response")
def nodeValue = holder.getNodeValue ("//*:errorInfo//*:descr")
log.info nodeValue
```